# Possible SQL injection in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, parameters, sql-injection

I have this piece of code in Ruby, which I believe could be a SQL injection spot

`@remaining_mdls = @remaining_mdls&.where("\"#{paginated_params_name}\" > ?", paginated_params_val) if paginated_params_val.present?`

This method checks for the availability of some objects, but I think it can be used for malicious purposes.

Is this safe or not?

Comment: That depends on where `paginated_params_name` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You're interpolating `paginated_params_name`.
The easiest fix would be to verify that `paginated_params_name` is included in a list of known columns:

```rb
ALLOWED_PAGINATED_PARAMS = %w(created_at updated_at ...)

if paginated_params_val.present?
  unless ALLOWED_PAGINATED_PARAMS.include?(paginated_params_name)
    fail "Unknown pagination param '#{paginated_params_name}'" 
  end
  @remaining_mdls = @remaining_mdls&.where("\"#{paginated_params_name}\" > ?", paginated_params_val)
end
```

Comment: paginated_params_name is a method, that returns something like this

```@paginated_params_name ||= request.headers['X-Pagination-Param'] || params[:paginated_param]```

Is it the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise a hacker could craft a request with a custom 'X-Pagination-Param' and run an SQL injection attack. The method you described has memoization: it caches the header value in a variable so it can be accessed quickly when that method is called multiple times, so this code should work without any performance implications.